# Как выразить в письменной форме эмоциональное "а"?

Tags: орфография

Как писать эмоциональное "а"? Например, в таких случаях:

Он: "Мне кажется у Иванова не всё дома."

Она: "Ты что, он вообще-то учёный и доктор наук".

Он: "Да я про другого, про его брата говорю."

Она: "Ааа, вон оно в чём дело!"

Вопрос: **Сколько букв "а" надо поставить в подобном случае?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"А-а-а, вон оно в чём дело?!"

Но три буквы выражают очень сильные эмоции, возможно, здесь и двух букв хватит.

**ИЗ словаря на Грамоте.ру:**

**1) А, частица.**

Разг. 1. (при повторном обращении). Употр. для привлечения внимания. Барышня, а барышня, помогите! 2. Употр. как вопросительный отклик на обращение. А, что вы сказали? Настя, Настя! - А?   И т.д

**2) А (обычно произносится удлинённо: а-а, а-а-а), межд.**

1. Выражает припоминание, узнавание при встрече, догадку и т.п. А-а! Так вы историк? Кто тут? - А-а! Это вы, доктор. И т.д

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы мне очень помогли. Зачёт. :)